# How to get the above element by using the event object that is under it using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

The scenario looks like below, right now it changes the color of "Test" text:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <a onclick="ChangeColor(this)">Test</a>
</div>

<script>
    function ChangeColor(e) {
       e.style.color = '#85BD49';
    }
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tYGU3/)

What I am trying to do is to change the background color and the text color of the div number class.

How can I do that by using the event object? I am not looking for a solution with jQuery or other ways.

Any kind of tips or help is appreciated I have tried parentNode and offsetNode but its not working.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `ChangeColorInfo(this)` in the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Or maybe `GetDocumentInfo(this)`...

Comment: Sorry, yes its suppose to be that, changed it

Comment: "I have tried `parentNode`" -- please show this attempt.

Comment: I am quite sure right now it does not change the color of `Test` :). Please at least put some effort into giving us an example that works. Creating a jsFiddle beforehand would help you in that. You should share some of the debugging steps you have taken too. It's hard to guess which part do you have a problem with.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.previousSibling

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol using parentNode changes the backgroundColor of class item

Comment: Also I should note that `e` is not an `Event` object in this case.

Comment: FWIW, you are not using the event object right now, and it's not necessary to use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parentNode` is the right thing to use, but you then need to get the right child.

`e.parentNode.children[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';` will work, assuming `.number` is the first child of the parent of the link.

You could also do:

```
e.parentNode.querySelector(".number").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Comment: Wrong. Wrong element.

Comment: Or more fragile: `e.previousElementSibling`